# Cannot access LDAP information after encrypting web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I followed the following Microsoft blog to help me encrypt the web config file across multiple server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede(v=vs.100).aspx

I have searched online but have not found an article where it shows how can I access the values after encrypting the file.

Comment: That very same article has a section on decrypting and states you shouldn't have to do anything to decrypt.  What kind of error or problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: @stephen.vakil, After encrypting the file, I just cannot use AD information. I had to decrypt the file in order to run AD credentials.

Comment: For some reason, I was able to get it work on a server and not on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything, it turns out that my IIS settings were not correct (not sure which ones) but I had to reset the IIS and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them from code as you would normally do.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"];
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDbConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

The .NET framework decrypts them when you access any of the encrypted config section from the application code.

You can't decrypt it yourself, if you want to open it in an XML document for example. To do this you have to manually encrypt them.

Comment: I have the settings above but I am still unable to use anything with AD.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Can you show the code you are using? And, also, please decrypt the config and make sure you have the required key and value in there.

Comment: Quick question, 

using
`aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication" -prov "MyProvider"`

vs

`aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings"  "MyApplication" -prov "MyProvider"`

cause any issues